# React Typescript application works fine but shows error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am currently building a react typescript application but when i use the mapping function in tsx it gives an error Property 'name' does not exist on type 'string | number'.
Property 'name' does not exist on type 'string'

```
import { Navbar } from "../components/Navbar";
import { doc, onSnapshot } from "firebase/firestore";
import { auth, db } from "../config/firebase";
import { FoodData, ICart } from "../interface/interface";

export const MyCart = () => {
    const user = auth.currentUser;
    const [cart, setCart] = useState<ICart | undefined>();
    // let cartArray : FoodData[] = [];

    useEffect(() => {
        onSnapshot(doc(db, "cart", `${user?.email}`), (doc) => {
            setCart(doc.data());
            console.log(cart?.myCart);
            // cartArray = [cart?.myCart];
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="h-full w-full ">
            <Navbar />

            <div className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-5 sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-4 ">
                {cart?.myCart?.map((item ) => (
                    <>
                        <div
                            key={id}
                            className=" flex flex-col justify-between "
                        >
                            <img
                                className="object-fit h-[250px] w-[350px]"
                                src={item.image}
                                alt=""
                            />
                            <h1 className="text-xl text-green-500">
                                {item.name}
                            </h1>
                            <h1 className="text-lg text-orange-500">
                                {item.price}
                            </h1>
                        </div>
                    </>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

For Reference this is my interfaces

````
    myCart?: [id: number, image: string, photo: string, price: string];
} ```

I get error in {item.name} , {item.price} and {item.image}
````

Comment: items in myCart is not object type but primitives. So you can't access it like item.price. You can use item itself. You need to change myCart interface

Comment: @Developertak did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You have declared an interface as array of specific elements `id`, `image`, `photo` and `price`  but not an array of objects having these as properties.

So the correct way should be sth like this

```
export default interface Item {
 id: number, 
 image: string,
 photo: string, 
 price: string
}
```

and the use this interface when you declare `myCart`

```
myCart?: Item[];
```